# Make BackgroundColor Equal To Border Color Using Random Color Generator in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I'm working full calendar to create a nice a easily viewable schedule for my client. Now I try to make every event has it's different color there for I use codes to generate random color in every page load but the problem right now is border color and background color are not equal. They are not equal because I also add random color with my border color. But when I try to assign the `getRandomColor` function into variable and put the variable in each border and background color of every event so it's surely output the same border and background color to an event but it will be applied for all event. So my goal are not meet.

How to make background color equal to border color when randomized color are present?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/aice09/w1pxfzcm/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }
    var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }

    var genColor =getRandomColor();
    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultDate: today,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [{
            title: 'Philippine Seven Corporation',
            start: '2017-05-01',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor()
        }, {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2017-05-07',
            end: '2017-05-10',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
            borderColor: getRandomColor()
        }, {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor()
        }, {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2017-05-16T16:00:00',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
            borderColor: getRandomColor()
        }, {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2017-05-11',
            end: '2017-05-13',
            backgroundColor: genColor,
            borderColor: genColor
        }, {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2017-05-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2017-05-12T12:30:00',
            backgroundColor: genColor,
            borderColor: genColor
        }, {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2017-05-12T12:00:00',
            backgroundColor: genColor,
            borderColor: genColor
        }, {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2017-05-12T14:30:00',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
            borderColor: getRandomColor()
        }, {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2017-05-12T17:30:00',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
            borderColor: getRandomColor()
        }, {
            title: 'Dinner',
            start: '2017-05-12T20:00:00',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
            borderColor: getRandomColor()
        }, {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2017-05-13T07:00:00',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
            borderColor: getRandomColor()
        }, {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2017-05-28',
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
            borderColor: getRandomColor()
        }],
        eventClick: function(event) {
            if (event.title) {
                alert(event.title);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

```css
#calendar {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Full Calendar-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/fullcalendar.min.css">
    <!--Bootstrap 3.3.7-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are looking for. You are calling a random color function separately for border color and background color. But, you want them to have the same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a parameter in getRandomColor to ask it to return the previously calculated color.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
  }
  var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  var prevColor;

  function getRandomColor(usePrev) {
    if (usePrev && prevColor)
      return prevColor;

    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    prevColor = color;
    return color;
  }

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    defaultDate: today,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{
      title: 'Philippine Seven Corporation',
      start: '2017-05-01',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: '2017-05-07',
      end: '2017-05-10',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: '2017-05-16T16:00:00',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Conference',
      start: '2017-05-11',
      end: '2017-05-13',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2017-05-12T10:30:00',
      end: '2017-05-12T12:30:00',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: '2017-05-12T12:00:00',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2017-05-12T14:30:00',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Happy Hour',
      start: '2017-05-12T17:30:00',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Dinner',
      start: '2017-05-12T20:00:00',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: '2017-05-13T07:00:00',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }, {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      url: 'http://google.com/',
      start: '2017-05-28',
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(true)
    }],
    eventClick: function(event) {
      if (event.title) {
        alert(event.title);
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#calendar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Full Calendar-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/fullcalendar.min.css">
<!--Bootstrap 3.3.7-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here has to do with how you are calling your function twice for each event. Take a look at each object in your 'events' array, especially the properties backgroundColor and borderColor. You are calling your function twice in each object.

```
{
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2017-05-07',
        end: '2017-05-10',
        backgroundColor: getRandomColor(), //<-- right here
        borderColor: getRandomColor() , // <-- calling  again, new color!
    },
```

Off the top of my head, a possible solution to this would be to create a function that generates event objects. Call the function 'getRandomColor' either inside that event generator or pass the color in as an argument.